# How to simplify multiple nested foreachs in c#

Tags: c#, nested-loops

Basically I have a method that is passed a list of custom objects. I'm using C#. Each of these contains a name and another list of other custom objects, I'll call these subObjects. These each have a name and a list of strings. I need to loop through all the strings, but keep track of the names of the parent object and subject for error logging purposes. Is there a cleaner, nicer way to do this than nesting foreachs?

```
foreach (var obj in listOfObjects) 
{
    foreach (var subObj in obj.subObjects)
    {
        foreach (var aString in subObj.strings)
        {
            if (some condition applies) 
            {
                //log error that includes obj, subObj, and subSubObj names, and aString.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the condition that you want to use in the `if` block?

Comment: You could use LINQ to do so, but I'm not sure it would be much clearer.

Comment: First replace the `subobj.strings` with `subObj.strings)` so it compiles. :)

I don't see any problem with this structure. It does what it has to. The only problem may be if inside that `if` you have to exit from the outer `foreach`, which would require a flag or a beautiful `goto`. ;)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: how would I do that?

Comment: I suggest what @Andrew said. The code makes sense; don't simplify more than you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a LINQ query to get all error cases

```
var errors = from obj in listOfObjects
             from subObj in obj.subObjects
             from aString in subObj.strings
             where /* your condition */
             select new { obj, subObj, aString };
```

and than iterate over them only:

```
foreach(var errorCase in errors)
{
    // log your error
}
```

or get the first one:

```
var error = errors.FirstOrDefault();
```

depending on your needs.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for, to me it is much easier to read and deal with. Thanks!

Comment: Beware that this solution could be less efficient because of creating new object for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to MarcinJuraszek answer, if linq to objects is preferred...

```
var errors = listOfObjects
  .SelectMany(obj => obj.subObjects
    .SelectMany(subObj => subObj.strings
      .Where(r => /* your condition */)
      .Select(aString => new { obj, subObj, aString })));
```

But there's nothing wrong with the code you posted. Clearly, yours is easier to follow at a quick glance.

Comment: That's exactly the same solution, except using different syntax. My code will get transformed by compiler to the same set of method calls, but is clearer and easy to read.